# Color QPushButton plain white

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I ould like to color a `QPushButton` in plain white, removing the 3D shade.
The following stylesheet:

```
  'background-color: rgb(255,255,255); \
   border-color: rgb(92,92,92);color: \
   rgb(92,92,92); \
   font: bold 22pt "Avenir"')
```

gives me the following output:

[image]

and I would like to have the button color white uniformly instead.

Comment: use `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: @eyllanesc the application already uses `app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Plastique"))` and I can't really change this, as all the other widgets look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button property that I needed to set is:

```
btn.setFlat(True)
```

with this, the button is uniformly white colored.